# Where to put the "i" flag in Firestore Security Rules str.matches(regex)?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing Security Rules for my Firebase Firestore project, but I can't seem to find a reference that exemplifies the correct syntax for using [**matches()** method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches) with a **regular expression** as the parameter.  Here's what I use now:

```
request.resource.data.str.matches("^[a-z0-9]+$");
```

My question is now, where to put the case-insensitive flag "i" in the expression? I tried some different combinations but didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: The linked RE2 language description suggests that flags occur in grouping syntax of the expression string.  It's not a function parameter that applies to the entire pattern, like you might find in other languages. Search this document for "flags" to see the syntax. https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. Did some reading up on RE2 and how it compares to PCRE. Helped to further clarify the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore security rules follow the [Google RE2 format](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) for regular expressions.

This means you can define a non-capturing group for your match, and flag that group to use case-insensitive matching with:

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.str.matches("(?i:^[a-z0-9]+)$");
```

Of course you can also simply expand the character group to include both uppercase and lowercase ASCII characters:

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.str.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
```

Comment: Great Frank. I was wondering how it is implemented without having to expand the character group. Which one do you consider a better practice?

Comment: Neither is better or worse. I prefer the latter myself because it's more idiomatic, so folks are more likely to recognize it at first glance, which is especially important when it comes to regular expressoins.